# 'this' pointer behaviour in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I have a basic understanding of this pointer in C++.While studying have come across the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
int x;
int y;
public:
//Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
Test obj1;
obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
obj1.print();
return 0;
}
```

My issue is why the compiler deosn't report an error where I am returning a this pointer in SetX and SetY functions but haven't stated the return type as a pointer?

Comment: `this` has type of `Test*`, `*this` has type of `Test`.

Comment: `setX` and `setY` should return a reference (`Test&`) for the code in `main` to work correctly.  Otherwise it will be modifying a temporary copy.

Comment: @interjay..Just wanted a more clearer explanation..If we are already returning the Test type then what is temporary variable and not the original one

Comment: If you return `Test` then it will return a copy of the object, and any modifications done on that copy will be lost. If you return `Test&` then it will return a reference to the same object. It's like the difference between `Test obj2=obj1` (giving two different objects) and `Test &obj2=obj1` (where both variables refer to the same object).

Comment: @OMKAR *While studying have come across the following code:* -- My radar is detecting that you copied the example wrong from wherever you got this code.  The example you gave is doing something called "function chaining", a well-known idiom.  Given that, I doubt the example you came across was returning a `Test` instead of a `Test&`.  The author(s) of wherever you got this example wouldn't make a mistake like this (returning `Test` instead of `Test&`).  If they did, find better material to get your C++ examples.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You guessed it right,the code actually returned Test& but  it was an exercise given(to cross check if the code worked fine) which didn't had an explanation for it..This had raised a doubt for me.

Answer (score 3):

This comes because you're returning `*this` not `this`.

`this` is the pointer to a object of type `Test`. This means the `this`-variable basically holds the address where the object is stored. To access the object on which `this` points you use the `*`.

So you're returning the actual object on which you `this` Pointer points at.

---

**EDIT**

The problem why your code does not work in the way you want it to do is caused by the fact, that you're working on the stack.

Let's take a look at the addresses:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
//Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
    Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
    Test setY(int b) {
        y = b;
        cout << this << endl; // >> 0x29ff18
        return *this;
    }
    void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{

    Test obj1;
    cout << &obj1 << endl; // >> 0x29ff10
    obj1 = obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
    cout << &obj1 << endl; // >> 0x29ff10
    //obj1.setY(20);
    obj1.print();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the object where `this` points at is at a different address within you `setY` method compared to the `main`. This is because the object is copied to the stackframe of the `setY` method - so within `setX` and `setY` you're working with a *copy* of `obj1`

If you're doing `obj1.setX(10).setY(20);`  <s>you basically copy the object `obj1` and use it within `setX` and the return object of `setX` is then used in `setY`. If you want to save the last copy, you have to reassign it to `obj1`.</s>

> Your solution to the problem works, but is grossly inefficient. The last paragraph describing what is happening is incorrect. setx is called with and uses obj1. sety is called with and uses copy of obj1. obj1 is then assigned copy of copy of obj1 returned by sety. The address doesn't change because obj1's storage is being overwritten, not replaced. Add a copy constructor and an assignment operator and you can watch what's really happening. The recommended solution is to use references to the same object throughout and chaining as per @πάνταῥεῖ 's answer below. – user4581301

Comment: Ok,as per your answer if the actual object is returned then it should change the value of y too.But the output for above code is : x = 10 y = 0

Comment: @falx You're on the completely wrong track. I don't have any clue why this was upvoted that much.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  where's my mistake? Would be nice to know the point

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'm explaining the background why this behaviour appears like this. So I am on the right track

Comment: Your solution to the problem works, but is grossly inefficient. The last paragraph describing what is happening is incorrect. `setx` is called with and uses `obj1`. `sety` is called with and uses copy of `obj1`. `obj1` is then assigned copy of copy of `obj1` returned by `sety`. The address doesn't change because `obj1`'s storage is being overwritten, not replaced. Add a copy constructor and an assignment operator and you can watch what's really happening. The recommended solution is to use references to the same object throughout and chaining as per @πάνταῥεῖ 's answer below.

Comment: Ok. I see my mistake. Thanks for the correction. I've simply tried to explain why it is like this and not how to solve it properly. I will replace my answer with yours.

Answer (score 2):

> My issue is why the compiler deosn't report an error where I am returning a this pointer in SetX and SetY functions but haven't stated the return type as a pointer?

It's completely valid syntax, so the compiler isn't supposed to return an error message. The problem is that you're using copies of `this*` with your return type.

---

To chain operations properly to operate on the original instance return a reference to `this`:

```
Test& setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
 // ^
Test& setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
 // ^
```

Otherwise you're returning an unrelated copy of your class.